# Simple function in JS doesn't work. Turn in tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript

I'am coding simple tic tac toe game in html+css+js. I have a problem with one function, which should write an "X" in postion 1 in my gameboard. When I click on postion 0, my O turn is visible but X turn doesn't work.

```
var gameBoard;
const user = "O";
const ai = "X";
const win = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [6, 4, 2]
]

const box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
startGame();

function startGame() {
    document.querySelector(".koniec").getElementsByClassName.display = "none";
    gameBoard = Array.from(Array(9).keys());
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        box[i].innerText = '';
        box[i].style.removeProperty('background-color');
        box[i].addEventListener('click', turnClick, false);
    }
}

function turnClick(square) {
    turn(square.target.id, user)
}

function turn(squareId, player) {
    gameBoard[squareId] = player;
    document.getElementById(squareId).innerText = player;
    console.log(gameBoard[0]);
}

function aiTurn(gameBoard) {
    if(gameBoard[0]=="O"){
        turn(1, ai);
    }
    console.log("asdasd");
}
```

Comment: You don't call the function`aiTurn()` anywhere.

Comment: also this `document.querySelector(".koniec").getElementsByClassName.display = "none";` is NOT correct. as it returns a list of elements NOT a single one where you can simply set the display property